# Magento 2 order status changing to pending again

Tags: magento-2.1, order-status

I have created my own order status return. If the user return one shipment the order status is changing to return but on making another shipment of same order it changes the order status to pending again. I have assigned it to processing. It should remain to return on making another shipment also. How to achieve that?

Comment: Are you assigning status return manually? and how you change status to processing? If you have made any customization then share your code.

Comment: No I am not changing it manually, but creating the shipment through Rest Api.